# Kate only shows up when I search for it, not in the application launcher (Plasma 5.21.4)

Tags: kde, .desktop, plasma-5, kate

Recently, I've been messing with the KDE Menu Editor. I wanted Kate to show up in two categories, Utilities and Development. This caused Kate to show up two times when I searched for it, so I removed the entry in Development. Kate still showed up two times when searching for it.

After trying to fix it, it only shows up one time when searching for it, but it doesn't show up in any of the categories. If I add an entry for Kate in the Menu Editor, it shows up two times when searching for it.

I want to be able to open Kate from the menu, and other things, but if it doesn't show up in the menu I won't be able to do any of those things. Is there a way to fix this, or do I just have to deal with it?

> **Details**
> Plasma 5.21.4, KDE neon 5.21

Comment: Did the menu editor make a backup? I not used this so maybe.

Comment: Actually, I just found out that it did! Thanks @Keith5001

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a KDE/Neon forum.  *KDE Neon and Kubuntu do share some support sites, alas this is not one of them*

Comment: Kubuntu is built with a specific (LTS) release of Qt used for all programs, Neon however uses a newer version of (non-LTS) Qt in order to use a newer Plasma desktop (along with other parts of the stack altered; KF5 etc) so your system (software stack) differs to Kubuntu & Ubuntu.  You should use a support site that is aware of the different software stack you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the backup menu editor made